# Accessing [Object] from POST response

Tags: javascript, json, object, httpresponse

How do I access the `[Object]` and return the value for each object to the console?

Response:

```
[ 'qpxExpress#tripsSearch',
  { kind: 'qpxexpress#tripOptions',
    requestId: 'EWwQPoK0fma2Wgz1x0PNGc',
    data: 
     { kind: 'qpxexpress#data',
       airport: [Object],
       city: [Object],
       aircraft: [Object],
       tax: [Object],
       carrier: [Object] },
    tripOption: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Request:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  body: {
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": "1"
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "SFO",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "2017-09-19"
      }
    ],
    "solutions": "1"
  }
},
  json: true
}
```

Comment: That is not the actual response from a POST call. If it is, you have bigger problems, like malformed JSON. Look at the actual raw data, rather than what the console spits out, and it should be clear.

Comment: How do I access the raw data? I have updated my request in the question above.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mark. Please see the answer below. I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to call on the nested object. 
Reading the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search) helped.

Updated code that returns the total price:

```
request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.trips.tripOption[0].saleTotal)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```